# element.text (similar to getText() from java) is not working and continuously returning empty string as value using python & selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation

**Problem** : **element.text is not working** and **continuously returning empty** even when I can see a real **value**

Solutions I have tried :

1. Tried finding element using different locator strategy: like xpath, class_name, css_selector, id & even combination of two locators adv strategy too
2. I have ensure page got loaded & ready, element is displayed, added condition with wait until element get clickable etc

Team, Let me know if you have faced and applied working solution for this issue. Thanks!

**System :**

- Python
- Selenium
- Edge browser & Chrome
- Target : any browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working solution**:

- Element is normal text field: **element.text**

```
    element = context.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="element-id"]')
    print("element.text >>> >>> >>> ", element.text)
```

- Element is input field:**input_element.get_attribute("value")**

```
    WebDriverWait(context.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#element-id")))
    input_element = context.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="element-id"]')
    getTextVal = input_element.get_attribute("value")
    print("element.text >>> >>> >>> ", getTextVal)
```